# Code C not working, maybe can be a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having problem with line 29.

> novo_no->proximo = tp;

Can anyone help me?

Error code:

> warning: assignment to ‘struct No *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘No *’ {aka ‘struct no *’} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
> 30 |     novo_no->proximo = tp;

```
No* insert(No *tp, int value)
{
    No* new_node = (No*) malloc(sizeof(No));
    new_node->data = value;
    new_node->next = tp;
    return new_node;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    bool exit = true;
    while (exit)
    {
        Stack *s;
        int opt, value;

        printf("Type your option: ");
        scanf("%i", &opt);

        switch (opt)
        {
            case 1:
                init(s);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Type a value: ");
                scanf("%i", &value);
                s->top = insert(s->top, value);
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                exit = false;
                break;
            default:
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `novo_no->proximo = tp;` in the code anywhere.

Comment: It seems that you renamed some types and variables. That is not really helpful. Please provide error messages actually matching your code. Also provide all relevant definitions and declarations. What is `tp`, How does `No` look like? That's the reason why you should provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: without more detailes there is not much we can help you with.
But theres one thing i noticed in the error, youre trying to assign struct no * to struct No *. notice the capital and non capital n.

Comment: What is the type of ```novo_no->proximo``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if it be clearer to have full code you may have problem with :

```
init(s);
```

In this code you pass a pointer not initialised. The init function will never be able to modify value of s.

Without seeing No strict definition it is impossible to find what is wrong is the line you show which is not visible in your code. (May be in init ?)